# Associating a type with a Swift enum case?

Tags: swift, enums

I’m using Swift 2, and I’d like to associate a `struct` type with each case in an `enum`.

At the moment, I’ve solved this by adding a function to the enum called `type` which returns an instance of the relevant type for each case using a switch statement, but I’m wondering if this is necessary. I know you can associate strings, integers etc. with a Swift enum, but is it possible to associate a type, too? All structs of that type conform to the same protocol, if that helps.

This is what I’m doing now, but I’d love to do away with this function:

```
public enum Thingy {

    case FirstThingy
    case SecondThingy

    func type() -> ThingyType {
        switch self {
        case .FirstThingy:
            return FirstType()
        case .SecondThingy:
            return SecondType()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "This is what I’m doing now, but I’d love to do away with this function" Why? What you're doing makes the choice perfectly. It associates the type with the case! This is what an enum method is _for_. I'd suggest you keep what you've got and move on.

Comment: I certainly could, but I know that with a string, etc., I can simply do `case FirstThingy = “FirstThingy”`. I was wondering if we had a means of doing that with an object yet.

Comment: So you're saying you want the type to be a raw value? Keep this, or better yet, make it a computed property. Then, you can actually use `thingy.type` instead of `thingy.rawValue`.

Comment: Interesting idea. Feel free to leave an answer if you want the kudos :)

Comment: You can certainly say `case FirstThing = "FirstThingy"`, but that's a string literal. Literals are the _only_ things you can treat in this way. A type, or FirstThingy instance, is not a literal. You could process the string literal in your `type()` function if it will make you feel better, but I would say that that's an undesirable level of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying that you want the raw value to be of type `ThingyType`, but that is not possible.

What you could do is make `type` a computed property, to remove the `()` and only needing to access it with `thingy.type`.

```
public enum Thingy {

    case FirstThingy
    case SecondThingy

    var type: ThingyType {
        switch self {
        case .FirstThingy:
            return FirstType()
        case .SecondThingy:
            return SecondType()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a matter of readable. ThingyType is not eligible to be a raw value. And I don't see how this answer is a material advance over the OP's original code.

Comment: @matt I removed the readability part and added that it isn't possible for it to be a raw value. This is better than the method as `type` is what a property typically is. `Thingy` has a type, not `Thingy` has a method to determine its own type.

Comment: The OP's question was "I’d love to do away with this function". But you didn't (and can't) "do away" with anything. The stuff inside the curly braces in a computed property _is_ a function (it's the `get` function, the getter function, except that you disguised this by omitting the word `get`). It's the _same_ function the OP said he wanted to do away with! So this "answer" is nothing but a sleight-of-hand - though good enough to satisfy the OP, I see...

Comment: The OP is clearly easily satisfied, learned something about Swift, and thought about something in a slightly different light. The OP felt he’d improved that one iota as an engineer, and considered others might benefit from the answer too. My apologies :)